# Issue with data conversion - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.0' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

This is a larger stored procedure that is supposed to take a batch of packaging data (i.e.pack dimensions) loaded by the user and if only Imperial units data has been provided it calculates and populates the dimensions in Metric units and vice versa. Below is a sample for the Height calculations (I am only pasting that since for each dimension the structure is the same and only the numbers vary). I keep however getting the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1 ---
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.0' to data type int

I want to add that no data in the form of 0.0 is in the load file, so I assume this is coming from a null which is why I tried handling those with the casts and nullif at the end.

```
select [Product ID] as [Product ID],
    [ID] as [PackRecordID],
    case when isnumeric([Height (Imperial)])= 1  and ([Height (Metric)] is null or [Height (Metric)] = '')    then
       case when [Height UOM (Imperial)] = 'FT' then nullif(try_cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Imperial)],0) as numeric)*0.3048) as varchar(20)),0)
          when [Height UOM (Imperial)] = 'IN' then nullif(try_Cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Imperial)],0)as numeric)*2.54) as varchar(20)),0)
          when [Height UOM (Imperial)] = 'YD' then nullif(try_Cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Imperial)],0)as numeric)*0.9144) as varchar(20)),0) else  nullif(try_cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Metric)],0) as numeric)*1)as varchar(20)),0) end 
                   else  nullif(try_cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Metric)],0) as numeric)*1)as varchar(20)),0)
                   end as [Height (Metric)], 

   case when [Height UOM (Imperial)] = 'FT'and ([Height UOM (Metric)] is null or [Height UOM (Metric)] = '') then 'm'
           when [Height UOM (Imperial)] = 'IN' and ([Height UOM (Metric)] is null or [Height UOM (Metric)] = '') then 'cm'
                 when [Height UOM (Imperial)] = 'YD' and ([Height UOM (Metric)] is null or [Height UOM (Metric)] = '') then 'm'  else try_cast([Height UOM (Metric)]as varchar(max)) end as [Height UOM (Metric)]
```

Comment: One option is to convert to money (for example) and then to int    Select try_convert(int,try_convert(money,'0.0'))

Comment: I think it boils down to you doing `nullif(varcharValue, 0)`. Try doing `nullif(varcharValue, '0')` instead.

Comment: Hi Viviansuarez! Just curious, is there a reason why you are casting it back as a varchar? To simplify things, I would leave it as a numeric. For example, like this, `[Height UOM (Imperial)] = 'FT' then nullif(try_cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Imperial)],0) as numeric)*0.3048)`...

Comment: Hi Katherine! I cast it back as varchar since I kept running into issues when putting it into the temp table with the UOMs (which are varchar) where the script grabs the new values from to then update the batch in the pre-staging table (i.e. the table where the data from the user's load file gets placed for processing). Granted, this was before I added some other things to the main script so it could be that that is not an issue anymore and I could simplify it as you suggest. :)

Answer (score 0):

The outermost `nullif` functions in each case-when block are trying to cast a varchar value to int to match their second parameter. Instead of `nullif(varcharValue, 0)` try using `nullif(varcharValue, '0')` instead, i.e.:

```sql
create table dbo.Product
(
    [ID] int not null,
    [Product ID] int not null,
    [Height UOM (Imperial)] varchar(2),
    [Height (Imperial)] varchar(20),
    [Height UOM (Metric)] varchar(2),
    [Height (Metric)] varchar(20),
);

insert dbo.Product values
    (1, 1, 'FT', '1.0', null, null),
    (2, 2, 'IN', '2.0', null, null),
    (3, 3, 'YD', '3.0', null, null),
    (4, 4, null, null, 'MM', '4.0');

select
    [Product ID],
    [ID] as [PackRecordID],
    case
    when isnumeric([Height (Imperial)])=1 and ([Height (Metric)] is null or [Height (Metric)] = '') then
      case
        when [Height UOM (Imperial)]='FT' then nullif(try_cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Imperial)],0) as numeric)*0.3048) as varchar(20)),'0')
        when [Height UOM (Imperial)]='IN' then nullif(try_Cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Imperial)],0) as numeric)*2.54) as varchar(20)),'0')
        when [Height UOM (Imperial)]='YD' then nullif(try_Cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Imperial)],0) as numeric)*0.9144) as varchar(20)),'0')
        else nullif(try_cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Metric)],0) as numeric)*1) as varchar(20)),'0') end
    else nullif(try_cast((try_cast(isnull([Height (Metric)],0) as numeric)*1) as varchar(20)),'0')
    end as [Height (Metric)],

    case
   when [Height UOM (Imperial)]='FT' and ([Height UOM (Metric)] is null or [Height UOM (Metric)] = '') then 'm'
   when [Height UOM (Imperial)]='IN' and ([Height UOM (Metric)] is null or [Height UOM (Metric)] = '') then 'cm'
   when [Height UOM (Imperial)]='YD' and ([Height UOM (Metric)] is null or [Height UOM (Metric)] = '') then 'm'
   else try_cast([Height UOM (Metric)] as varchar(max))
   end as [Height UOM (Metric)]
from dbo.Product;
```

Which returns:

```
Product ID  PackRecordID  Height (Metric)  Height UOM (Metric)
1           1             0.3048           m
2           2             5.08             cm
3           3             2.7432           m
4           4             4                MM
```